# Jhipster: hide entities from non-admin

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, jhipster

Greetings java hipsters!

I just generated a jhipster project and created some entities. I'd like to hide some entities by restricting them to only the admin user.  How do I achieve this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First read [Spring Security doc](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/current/reference/html/) then look at your project source code that was generated by JHipster: it's full of such examples, pay attention to:

- `SecurityConfiguration.java`
- `@Secured(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)` in `UserResource.java`

Then for the angular part, you can add a requirement for admin role in a state's definition like in `src/main/webapp/app/admin/configuration/configuration.state.js` (search `for authorities: ['ROLE_ADMIN']`). So for a `bank-account` entity, main state would be defined in `src/main/webapp/app/entities/bank-account/bank-account.state.js`.

This is for JHipster 3.x

Comment: One more thing: To hide the entities from menu, look into navbar.html - hiding from non-admins is already implemented there for some of the menu items. All you need to do is adding 
    has-authority="ROLE_ADMIN"
to the menu element.

Comment: thank you so much, that answer is very helpful

Answer (score 4):

I just describe how i blocked new entity("folder") on a bit more fresh version (JHipster 4.7.0):

to block access to endpoint I added new line in a file: **src/main/java/package path/config/SecurityConfiguration.java**:

```
.antMatchers("/api/profile-info").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/api/folders").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN) //new line
.antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
```

change **src/main/webapp/app/entities/folder/folder.route.ts**:

```
 data: {
    authorities: ['ROLE_USER'], // old 
    authorities: ['ROLE_ADMIN'],// new
    pageTitle: 'jmediaApp.folder.home.title'
 },
```

and to hide item from navbar you need to add `*jhiHasAnyAuthority="'ROLE_ADMIN'"` in `<li>` tag in **/src/main/webapp/app/layouts/navbar/navbar.component.html**:

```
<li *jhiHasAnyAuthority="'ROLE_ADMIN'">
```

Answer (score 1):

On the Gateway UI By Using react.js server following process can be followed.

1. Open `src/main/webapp/app/app.tsx` which contains all routing mechanism. Check the component `<Header ..{additional props added}.. />`
2. on `mapStateToProps` there is a function by the name `isAdmin` to check if the logged-in user is an admin. (Change this according to your ROLE. I am using ROLE_ADMIN so I left as it is.)
3. Go to `src/main/webapp/app/shared/layout/header/header.tsx`. This file contains all the navigation to the entities under `<EntitiesMenu >` component. pass the isAdmin prop to the EntitiesMenu component as `<EntitiesMenu admin={props.isAdmin} />`
4. Now Go to `src/main/webapp/app/shared/layout/menus/entities.tsx` change the respective path to

   `{

        props.isAdmin && (
            <MenuItem icon="asterisk" to="/entity/institute">
               <Translate contentKey="global.menu.entities.institute" 
               />
            </MenuItem>    )
   }`
   This helps in hiding the navigation links.
5. But if the user enters the specific path on the browser url, There is no validation on that. So change `src/main/webapp/app/entities/index.tsx` from `<ErrorBoundaryRoute ../>` to

`<PrivateRoute path={`${match.url}/institute`} component={Institute} hasAnyAuthorities={[AUTHORITIES.ADMIN]} />`

After this even if the user open the URL by mentioning it in the browser search bar, Jhipster validates if the user has got the role or not. If not simply access denied page will be shown.