# How to hide entity from USER

Tags: jhipster

I am just new to jhipster. I am searching how to hide entity from USER and only visible to ADMIN. Is there any configuration? or do I have to manually code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jhipster: hide entities from non-admin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38377391/jhipster-hide-entities-from-non-admin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the following to the entity link in the navbar.html

hasAuthority="ROLE_ADMIN".

You can search this in the same html for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you use only hasAuthority="ROLE_ADMIN", you have hide the entity from front end. In this case if you hit in the browser with entity name in thelink, you will be able to access the restricted link. To avoid this, you need to change " authorities:" in the state of that entity.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted the tested process to allow entities for a specific role in a already [existing post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57990464/6821445).